# Launch local Plex browser client and play some content (i.e. permalink)

Tags: browser, python, plex, permalink

On my client machine, I can query my Plex server for media matching a given string using [python-plexapi](https://github.com/pkkid/python-plexapi) and I get results.

```
for section in plex.library.sections():
    items = section.search('Die Hard')
```

I want to then play the first result in my local browser on the same machine. Looking around at the docs, python-plexapi supports the [`getStreamURL()`](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/base.html?highlight=getstreamurl#plexapi.base.Playable.getStreamURL) method, however, this method returns the stream itself, instead of instructing it to be played in the browser (it would be streamed in an application like VLC, which is not what I am looking for). python-plexapi can also instruct the item to be [played](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/base.html?#plexapi.base.Playable.play) through a [client](https://python-plexapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/client.html). The problem with this is that my local browser rarely appears in the list of connected devices, so this approach is extremly unreliable.

What I am basically looking for is a Plex permalink I can use to get the browser open to the correct content (and have it playing). Something like this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(URL)
```

where `URL` contains some Plex ID of the first item returned by python-plexapi. I found the metadata page URL:

```
http://<IP_ADDRESS>:32400/web/index.html#!/server/<SOME_TOKEN>/details?key=%2Flibrary%2Fmetadata%2F<CONTENT_ID>
```

however, I cannot find a URL to the player with this content loaded.

Plex Version 1.10.1.4602